# How to connect to MongoDB using PhantomJS

Tags: mongodb, phantomjs

I'm Running OSX. Thought I could find documentation somewhere, but could not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* use a MongoDB REST client:

- [Sleepy.Mangoose](https://github.com/10gen-labs/sleepy.mongoose): It's the best IMO
- [MongoDB REST](https://github.com/tdegrunt/mongodb-rest): It looks promising, but is not complete yet and has some weird bugs (for example, it refused to send large requests (more than 80,000 characters) and it took me 3 hours to find what was wrong with it)
- [MongoDB Java REST server](https://sites.google.com/site/mongodbjavarestserver/home)

You can connect directly to the rest server from you injected javascript (use jQuery's `ajax` method or simply use `xmlhttprequest`), but I think it's better to do it inside PhantomJS's `evaluate` method (because if the page you're parsing has javascript errors, your the injected javascript might not work properly).

---

But I personally don't like the idea of a REST server for PhantomJS. I think It's better to write your whole application in [NodeJS](http://nodejs.org) and use [`phantomjs`](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node) module to run PhantomJS. This way, you don't have to go the REST way and can use the (now official) [MongoDB Native Node Driver](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native), which is potentially many times faster than the REST servers (because it doesn't require JSON HTTP serialization/deserialization, among other things).

Comment: phantomjs in node seems like a lot of pain too.  They basically host a page in the background and talk through websocket, which means you will be also running express.  It can't be too performant.

Comment: Sleepy.Mongoose link is broken.