# Load fixture on setup, clean database on teardown using casperjs

Tags: mongodb, phantomjs, integration-testing, casperjs

I'm new to casperjs, but I do have experience with automated testing. 
I am trying to figure out how to do a proper `setup`/`teardown` to leave a MongodDB database in a predictable state for each test.

Ideally I would like to connect to my database, load a fixture on `setup`, then drop the collection on `teardown`, but it seems there is no straight way to connect to MongoDB from casperjs/phantomjs.

I've spent some time searching and I found quite a few questions around about connecting to MongoDB from casperjs/phantomjs. 
This answer seems to be the closer to an accepted solution:
[How to connect to MongoDB using PhantomJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220487/how-to-connect-to-mongodb-using-phantomjs/10231923#10231923).
But the proposed alternatives are broken/abandoned and the whole idea of using REST is not what I look for.

I feel it's such a basic requirement for integration tests that I can't believe there is no better solution.
Any better alternatives/ideas? Anyone having the same problem?

Thanks a lot!